# How to do semi-supervised learning for regression

Tags: scikit-learn, regression, semi-supervised-learning

I am doing regression analysis on a data set with over 20000 samples using scikit learn. Trying to use regression models to fit three features to label which is a score ranges from 0 to 10. Problem is only 100 of the data has a known score. The rest are all unlabeled.

Semi-supervised learning seems to work well with classification problems using methods like label-propagation. I wonder if it works for regression problems as well. If so, where can I find any examples for labeling unlabeled data based on similarity?

Comment: If the scores are only integers from 0 to 10, did you try semi-supervised classification on this data?

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar dataset, I came across ***covarite shift*** technique of Machine Learning. As you have changes in the distribution of the input variables in training data. Though the predictions might also be wrong using this.